# Scandit with Phonegap giving Class not found error

Tags: android, cordova, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to use the Scandit SDK Community edition plugin in my Phonegap 3.3.0 app. I've followed the instructions at https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin and used the sample code provided, but when I run the app and click the "Scan" button, I get an alert saying Failed: Class not found.

I've tried adding `<gap:plugin name="com.mirasense.scanditsdk.plugin" />` to my config.xml but it makes no difference.

Also tried adding `<plugin name="ScanditSDK" value=com.mirasense.scanditsdk.plugin" />` to the config.xml but again no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scandit support resolved the problem by adding

```
<feature name="ScanditSDK">
  <param name="android-package" value="com.mirasense.scanditsdk.plugin.ScanditSDK"/>
</feature>
```

to the config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

This is Christian from Scandit Support. To help you with your issue, we would need to know a couple more details.

Which version of the Scandit SDK (for Cordova) did you download?
Did you download the packaged Cordova plugin from your account at Scandit.com? Or did you use the source code available at https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin, edited the plugin.xml file manually and downloaded the native libs from your Scandit account?

We generally recommend to use the former approach and to use the Cordova command-line interface to install our pre-packaged plugin (as described in the README.md). Did you get an error message when you executed the CLI *plugin add* command? e.g.

cordova plugin add 'path to downloaded,unzipped ScanditSDK Plugin for Phonegap/Cordova'

Comment: Thanks Christian.

To answer your questions:
I downloaded the file named scanditsdk-phonegap-community_4.2.0.zip from the Scandit site at https://ssl.scandit.com/account/sdk
I then followed the instructions in the README.md file for setting up the sample project using the CLI
When I ran cordova plugin add 'path to downloaded,unzipped ScanditSDK Plugin for Phonegap/Cordova', it gave this message: "Installing "com.mirasense.scanditsdk.plugin" for android".
Hope this helps. Otherwise I could try sending you the contents of the sample project in a zip?